# Manipulating database data with Laravel without using migrations

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a couple of tables with special names that I imported through a SQL file (this is required, it's for school, all tables must have our initials before the actual table name), I have seen that most of the tables through Laravel are created with a migration, I want to use Eloquent for the CRUD but I don't want to use migrations, what's the approach for it? what should I investigate to make this? I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel migrations need for make your databse easly. If you already make database you can use Eloquent model like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class School extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'school';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: if i want to make for example an insert using eloquent do i have to declare fillables with the same names as my columns? like: `protected $fillable = ['my1', 'my2'];`

Comment: if you want to use `create()` or `update()` method then yes

Comment: other case you can use `$model = new Model(); $model->my1  = 'val1'; $model->my2  = 'val2'; $model->save();`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your model you can define the table for that model. for example if you have a table named a_school, in the A_SchoolModel.php you can define the table as below.

```
protected $table = 'a_school';
```

Also if the database engine for app is InnoDB, go to config->database and set `mysql => [ 'engine' => 'innoDB',]`